# grep not extracting required list

Tags: bash, list, grep

I have a sequence IDs (seqID) that I'm trying to use to extract from a larger file (singleline.fasta)
seqID id formatted as so:

```
ID1
ID6
ID10
```

Singleline.fasta is formatted

```
ID1
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
ID2
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
ID3
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I am trying to extract the matching header and the line below to get a file reading

```
ID1
XXXXXXXXXXXX
ID6
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
ID10
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The line I used was:

```
grep -A1 -w -f seq_ID singleline.fasta > selected_genes.fasta
```

However, this is just copying the entirety of singleline.fasta into selected_genes.fasta rather than extracting the lines listed in seqID. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Are there any blank lines in the seq_ID file?

Comment: Are the IDs literally `ID6` and so on, or do they contain special symbols like `*`? Try using `-F`. Also instead of `-w` you might want to use `-x`.

Comment: There aren't any blank lines in the file. I tried both -F and -x as you suggested and no such luck. The IDs do have "." in them i.e. ID.peg.1

Comment: And the desired output is in the third grey block. Thanks so much for the suggestions so far!

Comment: make sure your files have the right line endings.  Perhaps run `dos2unix` if sourced from windows...

Comment: Hi karakfa! Just tried that and the output hasn't changed. I'm really quite flummoxed!

Answer (score 1):

Grep processes line by line so it won't see the newlines. There are multiple easy ways to do this. Easiest way is to run singleline.fasta through

```
paste -d",\n" -s singleline.fasta | grep "whatever" |tr "," "\n"
```

This combines the label and data into a single line with the label and data separated by a comma which can be grepped and then split back into multiple lines with tr.

Rather than trying to do everything in one line, It will be easier to use command substitution while catting seqID.